# Problems installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS using USB and bootable DVD - Mac

Tags: 12.04, usb, dvd

Im trying to install the developer version of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Desktop Developer edition. It's the 64 bit download version as my mac's a Intel Core 2 Duo. According to the Ubuntu website, I should be able to install Ubuntu using a bootable USB or DVD. The USB first;

Long story short, it failed. I think this has something to do with Apple nailing down its software. I could select the USB when I held Alt on the keyboard - 2 USB's appeared and none of them worked; the screen would go black and stay black.

The DVD approach hasn't fared much better. I bought new DVD-RW DVD's with a capacity of 4.7GB each. Again, according to the Ubuntu site, [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-mac-osx), all I need to do is open **Disk Utility** and burn the ISO to the DVD. Then press C on start up and boot from there.

I did that but here's the problem - the DVD just keeps getting ejected by the mac. 
What's the problem here? If I can't install Ubuntu onto this Mac using USB or DVD - what else can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done, based on how I wanted it installed. I tried various options and none of them worked. The only alternative is to install VirtualBox and use it to run Ubuntu.